# Получаю разные значения при вычитании даты на разных устройствах

Tags: android, дата

Проблема в следующем:
Приложение должно отображать рабочую смену в графике на выбранную дату. Для этого оно отсчитывает количество дней с определенной даты, делит на 12 (длинна цикла) и отображает остаток от деления.

На одном устройстве алгоритм сработал правильно. Однако при установке приложения на другое устройство появилась ошибка в один день.

```
    String d1 = "02.11.1945"; 
    Int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
    Int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
        month = month + 1; 
    Int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

String d2 = (day +"." + month + "." + year);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
  Date date1 = null; 
  Date date2 = null; 

try { date1 = format.parse(d1); date2 = format.parse(d2); 
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
  long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
  long days = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
  Long result = days%12;
```

Когда вывел итоговые значения всех переменных в TextViev оказалось, что на разных телефонах **days** имеет разницу в один день.
Соответственно проблема в расчете **difference**.
Почему такое может быть, и как это исправить?
(Дата **d1** выбрана случайно)

Comment: а что на счет `date1` и `date2` они верны?

Comment: Часовые пояса одинаковые на обоих устройствах?

Answer (score 0):

**date1** и **date2** одинаковые.
А вот часовые пояса разные. Но как это может повлиять?

Сейчас покопася, и выяснил, что глюки начинаются если стоит часовой пояс **Екатеринбург**. Он в настройках числится как GMT+6, а вообще у нас GMT+5. Исправил пояс на другой GMT+5 и все корректно заработало .

Проблему решил проверкой правильности подсчета. Добавил следующий код

```
String dTest = "01.11.2016";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;
    Date TestDate = null;
    try {
    date1 = format.parse(d1);
    date2 = format.parse(d2);
    TestDate = format.parse(dTest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    long days =  difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


    long diffTest = TestDate.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    long daysT =  diffTest / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Long resultT = daysT%12; //при правильном расчете получаем ноль
    days = days - resultT; //если нет, то количество дней уменьшается на погрешность
    Long result = days%12; //и остаток от деления все равно получаем правильный.
```

Вобщем добавил проверку расчета количества дней. При правильной проверке между двумя датами остаток от деления получаем ноль. Если расчеты не верны, то вычитаем тестовый остаток из полученного числа дней. В конечном счёте все-равно имеем верный остаток от деления.
Всем спасибо! Вопрос закрыт!